# Hibernate - Of three columns, at least one must be not-null

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity that has three foreign key to other entities:

```
public class MyClass {
    // ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    public Customer getCustomer() {
      return customer;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "creditDossier_id")
    public CreditDossier getCreditDossier() {
       return creditDossier;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "insuranceDossier_id")
    public InsuranceDossier getInsuranceDossier() {
       return insuranceDossier;
    }

    // ...
}
```

How can I add a restriction that guarantees that at least one of the *Dossier is not null.

Answer (score 4):

You should write a method with annotating `@PrePersist` in your entity class, which will check the your restrictions before persist.

```
   @PrePersist
   public void checkValidation(){
       if(isValid()){
           // send for persist.
       }
       else{
           //throws Exception.  
       }         
   }

   private boolean isValid(){
        return customer!=null || creditDossier!=null || insuranceDossier!=null;
   }
```

Comment: Will that restriction be present in the DB? I will be inserting entites with Smooks (SQL script).

Comment: No, obviously it won't be present in DB. The solution is in Java side. For SQL scripts you need another approach which will be different depending on your DB.